# Whisper message & voicemail functionality in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I would like to have a tracking number in Twilio that will forward to my cell phone, provide a whisper message, record the call, and go to voicemail if I don't answer.  Then I would like the voicemail recording emailed to me.

I've figured out how to use Twilio Studio and Twimlets to do everything, except the Whisper message.

I've found several threads that teach how to integrate a Whisper message using TwiML Bins, but I none of them include voicemail capability that I need.

I'm not a programmer and I want to be able to duplicate these functions on other tracking numbers that I own.

Can anyone assist me with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post.

Outsmart Voice Mail with Human Detection Using Keypress Prompts
https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Say></Say>` verb to whisper message and use the `<Record>` verb to record the call.
You'll get the recording of your call in an endpoint, which you can then email to your address with sendrid or whatever you want.